# C# Recursive algorithm error using a.Skip(1) as input

Tags: c#

[image: image of the code and error]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    public static bool Aa(int[] a, int k)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
            if (a[0] + a[i] == k)
                return true;
        if (a.Length != 1)
            Aa(a.Skip(1), k);
        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1 };
        Console.WriteLine(Aa(a, 10));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The following build error occurs on the recursive method call `Aa(a.Skip(1), k);`

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'int[]'

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please consider using more descriptive method and variable names. "Aa" doesn't convey any meaning towards what the method does, neither does "a" and "k" for what data they are expecting.

Comment: Do you understand what an IEnumerable is? Have you experimented with chaining methods after `Skip()`? There are some methods that start with `To..`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert IList or IEnumerable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array)

Comment: Call [`.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToArray__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) on the `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: You want to pass in an array where you want ot skip first element so you should use: a.Skip(1).ToArray()

Comment: Please consider writing function `Aa` in such a way that it will accept not just an array of integers, but _any_ kind of enumerable of integers. Not only does it fit LINQ better (thereby fixing the error), it will also be more efficient (`.ToArray()` is pretty poor advice here). BTW, you are discarding the return value of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass an Array obj to Aa Like this :

```
a.Skip().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most LINQ methods,
[Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip)
is designed to work with enumerables, not arrays.

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Skip<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count);
```

It is OK to pass in an array, but it will implicitly be
[upcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)
to the more generalized type
[IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1),
and that is also the type that will be returned by `Skip`.

```
int[] whatGoesIn = {1, 2, 3};
IEnumerable<int> whatComesOut = whatGoesIn.Skip(1);
```

You cannot safely
[downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)
the return value to `int[]`.
As proposed by others, LINQ has a convenient method
[ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray),
but think twice before using it.
The method will create a completely new array object, which is often a total waste of memory as well as CPU time.
Only use this method
[when you really need an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692082/have-arrays-in-net-lost-their-significance).

In your case, `ToArray` would have to be called once for every element of the original array.
This will put a lot of strain on the heap.
With a big array, you will be seeing a lot of GC.

Make up your mind: either use `Skip`, or use arrays. Don't do both.

### Option 1: Skip, without arrays

Follow the LINQ philosophy and use enumerables all the way.
This has the advantage that it will work on *any* enumerable: arrays, collections, lists, dictionaries...

So instead of declaring parameter `a` as an array:

```
public static bool Aa(int[] a, int k)
```

declare `a` as an enumerable:

```
public static bool Aa(IEnumerable<int> a, int k)
```

Notice this will immediately eliminate your error. It will introduce a few new ones though. Like in the `for` loop; `IEnumerable<int>` has no property `Length`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
    if (a[0] + a[i] == k)
        return true;
```

Upon close inspection, you are basically looking for an array element that equals `k - a[0]`. Just use
[Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains):

```
bool found = a.Skip(1).Contains(k - a.First());
if (found) return true;
```

Another reference to `Length`:

```
if (a.Length != 1)
    Aa(a.Skip(1), k);
return false;
```

That's weird; you call `Aa` but don't do anything with its return value. You probably meant this:

```
if (a.Length != 1)
    return Aa(a.Skip(1), k);
return false;
```

I will not use [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count),
as it is potentially expensive on long enumerables.
I am not actually interested in the exact length; we can stop counting after the second element.

```
return a.Skip(1).Any() && Aa(a.Skip(1), k);
```

After refactoring, the whole function becomes a one-liner:

```
public static bool Aa(IEnumerable<int> a, int k)
{
    return a.Skip(1).Contains(k - a.First()) || (a.Skip(1).Any() && Aa(a.Skip(1), k));
}
```

I'd recommend to make the function robust against zero-length arrays by moving the 'Any' check to the front.

```
public static bool Aa(IEnumerable<int> a, int k)
{
    return a.Any() && (a.Skip(1).Contains(k - a.First()) || Aa(a.Skip(1), k));
}
```

### Option 2: arrays, without Skip

Arrays have one big advantage over enumerables: they are **fast**.
OP's `for` loop is faster than my call to `Contains`.
There is no need to use `Skip`; just start iterating at a different index.

```
public static bool Aa(int[] a, int k, int start = 0)
{
    for (int i = start + 1; i < a.Length; i++)
        if (a[start] + a[i] == k)
            return true;
    if (start < a.Length)
        return Aa(a, k, start + 1);
    return false;
}
```

This is twice as fast as the `ToArray` solution, and three times as fast as enumerables.

### Note

I'm not too thrilled about the use of recursion here,
because nesting depth is proportional to array length.
For long arrays, this may cause a stack overflow.
In theory, the compiler *could* optimize away the tail recursion, but even in .NET 6, it doesn't
(although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934888/2485966) suggests otherwise).

Comment: Skip works fine on arrays, it returns an IEnumerable, thats the issue

Comment: @pm100 Exactly my point. After my changes, `Aa` still _accepts_ an array. It just no longer _demands_ an array.

Comment: no the solution is to add .ToArray() after skip

Comment: @pm100 Bad idea to let `ToArray` create a new array for every recursive call; I tried and witnessed lots of GC on big arrays. Besides, why `Skip` when you can simply increment an index variable to advance your starting point? I edited my answer to clarify this.